# Синтаксис при подключении src=<%= на NetCore

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webpack

подскажите как подключить данный плагин на языке Net Core?

```
<body>
<script src=<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.path %>/tinymce4.7.5/tinymce.min.js></script>
....
</body>
```

Comment: Если проект готовый, то установить ноду, правый клик на файле package.json или на dependencies -> npm и пункт меню update. Если это у вас образец и нужно воспроизвести в пустом проекте, то сначала поставьте ноду, проверьте пути, создайте npm конфиг и так далее.

Comment: node.js стоит, проблема что это не html, а cshtml - т.е. C# index который запускает vue application